# Выбор между JSON и базой данных

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, json

Хочу реализовать проект, в рамках которого можно регистрировать аккаунты, просматривать их список и удалять их. Собираюсь писать на NodeJS. Встал вопрос по поводу того, что использовать для хранения аккаунтов. Я знаю только 2 варианта - JSON и Базы данных. Подскажите, что выбрать и почему? Буду благодарен

Answer (score 3):

Сначала нужно понять, что часто оперировать с файлами трудозатратно и при большом количестве операций будут возникать проблемы.

Почитайте про Базы данных, для чего они нужны:

https://thecode.media/db/

Comment: Спасибо, узрел отличия между JSON и базой данных. И, кста, классный ресурс)

Answer (score 0):

Не важно на чём в начале лишь бы быстро выйти в продакшн. Пишите на для начала на json если оно вам ближе. Только для доступа к данным абстрагируйтесь от источника. Примените паттерн стратегию - напишите единый интерфейс доступа к данным. По мере развития проекта и нагрузки будете имплементировать ваш интерфейс под различные источники данных там может и облака и оперативки и что угодно.